# Fail to apply colors to object in WEBGL

Tags: javascript, glsl, webgl

Update to the question, the objective is to draw a circle that each vertice that has a random color.

I have all 1500 vertices with random colors but the colors in the circle appear to have a pattern.

Why is this happening? That could not cause by the logical of `Math.random` right?

What's the logic behind the coloring?

[image]

```
var VSHADER_SOURCE =
  'attribute vec4 a_Position;\n' +
  'attribute vec4 a_Color;\n' +
  'varying vec4 v_Color;\n' + // varying variable
  'void main() {\n' +
  '  gl_Position = a_Position;\n' +
  '  gl_PointSize = 10.0;\n' +
  '  v_Color = a_Color;\n' +  // Pass the data to the fragment shader
  '}\n';

// Fragment shader program
var FSHADER_SOURCE =
  'precision mediump float;\n' + // Precision qualifier (See Chapter 6)
  'varying vec4 v_Color;\n' +    // Receive the data from the vertex shader
  'void main() {\n' +
  '  gl_FragColor = v_Color;\n' +
  '}\n';

function main() {
  // Retrieve <canvas> element
  var canvas = document.getElementById('webgl');

  // Get the rendering context for WebGL
  var gl = getWebGLContext(canvas);
  if (!gl) {
    console.log('Failed to get the rendering context for WebGL');
    return;
  }

  // Initialize shaders
  if (!initShaders(gl, VSHADER_SOURCE, FSHADER_SOURCE)) {
    console.log('Failed to intialize shaders.');
    return;
  }

  // Write the positions of vertices to a vertex shader
  var n = initVertexBuffers(gl,canvas);
  console.log(n);
  if (n < 0) {
    console.log('Failed to set the positions of the vertices');
    return;
  }

  // Specify the color for clearing <canvas>
  gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);

  // Clear <canvas>
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

  // Draw the rectangle
  gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, n);
}

function initVertexBuffers(gl,canvas) {
  
  
  var Cx = 0;
  var Cy = 0;
  // var rect = ev.target.getBoundingClientRect();
  var r  = 300.0/canvas.height;
  var vertices = [];

  for (var i = 1; i <= 500; i++) {
      vertices.push(Cx);
      vertices.push(Cy);

      vertices.push(Cx+r*Math.sin(i-1));
      vertices.push(Cy+r*Math.cos(i-1));

      vertices.push(Cx+r*Math.sin(i));
      vertices.push(Cy+r*Math.cos(i));

      // vertices.push(Math.random(),Math.random(),Math.random())
    }
    

    var vertexColors = [];

  for (var i = 1; i <= 1500; i++){
    vertexColors.push(Math.random(),Math.random(),Math.random(),1)

  }
  var n = vertices.length/2;

  console.log(vertices);



  // Create a buffer object
  var vertexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  if (!vertexBuffer) {
    console.log('Failed to create the buffer object');
    return -1;
  }

  // Bind the buffer object to target
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
  // Write date into the buffer object
  // gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices, gl.STATIC_DRAW);
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

  // var FSIZE = vertices.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT;
  var a_Position = gl.getAttribLocation(gl.program, 'a_Position');
  if (a_Position < 0) {
    console.log('Failed to get the storage location of a_Position');
    return -1;
  }
  // Assign the buffer object to a_Position variable
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(a_Position, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

  // Enable the assignment to a_Position variable
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(a_Position);
  

  var colorBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, colorBuffer);
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertexColors), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

  // Get the storage location of a_Position, assign buffer and enable
  var a_Color = gl.getAttribLocation(gl.program, 'a_Color');
  if(a_Color < 0) {
    console.log('Failed to get the storage location of a_Color');
    return -1;
  }
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(a_Color, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(a_Color);  // Enable the assignment of the buffer object

  return n;
}
```

Comment: You have 1500 vertices, but only 6 colors. You need 1 color for each vertex.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Thank you, you solved that part of the question but the random coloring appears to have a pattern.

Comment: Every random algorithm has a pattern. It is an algorithm that simulates randomness. Anyway this was not part of the original question. Edit questions only to improve them, but don't turn a question into an entirely new question.

Comment: @Rabbid76 You are right. Would you like to post an answer so I can accept it so closing the question>